# Tornado - Best Practices to connect to MySQL database and Redis Instance via Tornado

Tags: mysql, redis, thread-safety, tornado

What are the points to remember or best practices to connect to MySQL database and Redis Instance from Tornado according to the scenario given below?

**Scenario 1** -

> - Tornado, MySQL db and Redis instance, all running on the same host.
> - No. of CPU cores = 2
> - No. of Tornado Instances = 2 (i.e 2 separate processes of Tornado running the same app).
> - 1 instance of MySQL db and Redis.
> - Tornado connecting to the MySQL database and Redis instance via different async libraries for each of them via connection pools.

**Question 1** : Since there are 2 tornado processes, what is the thread safety points to note while connecting to MySQL db and Redis via connection pools from these 2 tornado processes? Any mutex or locking mechanism to take care of? Or those are automatically handled internally? Specially for redis using tornado_redis and redis-py as libraries.

**Scenario 2** - A general scenario

> - There are multiple tornado processes, more than 2 according to the no. of cpu cores and other factors.
> - MySQLdb and Redis running on same host as Tornado.
> - Tornado connecting to MySQL and Redis via connection pools of the respective async libraries.

**Question 2** - What is the best practice and thread safety notes to follow here?